# Rails routes adding resource_id to url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Hi i have a rails app and i use different namespaces in it like user, admin etc.

My url's under user namespaces as

```
'/user/:controller_name' but i want to
```

use it like

```
'/library/:library_id/user/:controller_name'
```

Users has one-to-one relationships with libraries. And i can get current users library id.

when i tried to make it with path parameter in route like

```
namespace :user, path: "library/user" do 
  ...
end
```

it is working but i couldnt get id.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This does not work?

```
namespace :user, path: "library/:library_id/user" do 
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but when i do this i need to add parameter to every url in application. For example i have link_to user_group_path(group) when i use this i need to use all of them as user_group_path(@library_id, group). Is there a any possible way to achive without changing link helpers

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this is wat you are looking for

```
  resources :libraries do
    namespace :users do
      resources :resource_name
    end
  end


# Output for me
/libraries/:library_id/users/controller_name/new(.:format)
/libraries/:library_id/users/controller_name/:id/edit(.:format)
. 
.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
resources :libraries do
  member do
    resources :user do
      collection do
        resources :controller_name
      end
    end 
  end 
end
```